# how to display text in iOS as a fire using particle system

Tags: ios, objective-c, particle-system

I am making a game wherein I need to show score text written with fire animation one letter at a time.

I am aware of the particle system in iOS but how do I plug it in to say an uttextview ? If anybody can provide some sample code it will be of great help.

I am currently looking at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial) tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Core Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Using the core text you can draw the test one by one and can add fire effect as well.

Comment: K i will give it a try. By the way is Core Text like attributed strings ?

Comment: Yes it is like attributed text.